# What are advantage of Isilon OneFS File System Access Api over accessing the file system using SMB or NFS?

Tags: nfs, smb, emc, isilon, onefs

I want to create some utility that read/write the files with permission (ACL) from/to `Isilon` server. This utility will access the server either on LAN or VPN. Here my main concern is to achieve performance too for file/folder enumeration and copy files data with attributes/acl/timestamp too.

As I know, you can access the file storage using `SMB` if server is on Windows server else `NFS` if server is on unix/linux.

so I want some basic information that in what scenarios `OneFS` Api's are better than accessing directly over NFS/SMB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Isilon admin at a big company. *TL;DR Its just another way to access your files*

Most of my clients-systems access their files using SMB, and a smaller number use NFSv3.  Generally NFS is best suited to Unix clients, and SMB is best with Windows, but you can mount SMB with Linux and you can run an NFS client on Windows.  Probably the biggest advantage with NFS/SMB is they are commonly used protocols that most IT admins are familiar with.

API access would be the best approach if you are already writing custom software, or implementing a web framework that was geared toward REST API integration.  If implementing using REST API, then Isilon's API access might be the easiest choice.

Comment: Drat - That answer was intended for a different question.  Doh!